# Is it good to samplesized image when binding in recyclerview ViewHolder?

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap

I want to build an android application and some images in it with recyclerView. I wonder if it good to use Bitmapfactory.option to reduce the image load time by the system when binding the view in recyclerView adapter ? or it will take more memory ?
here is my recyclerView adapter

```
package net.renotekno.rifqi.cardviewtraining.Adapter;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import net.renotekno.rifqi.cardviewtraining.Data.Data;
import net.renotekno.rifqi.cardviewtraining.MainActivity;
import net.renotekno.rifqi.cardviewtraining.R;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class LocationRecycler extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LocationRecycler.ViewHolderLocation> {
    private final MainActivity mContext;

public LocationRecycler(MainActivity mainActivity) {
    mContext = mainActivity;
}

@Override
public ViewHolderLocation onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolderLocation(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolderLocation holder, int position) {
    holder.bindItem(position, mContext);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return Data.locations.length;
}

public static class ViewHolderLocation extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @BindView(R.id.placeTitle) TextView mPlaceTitle;
    @BindView(R.id.countryTitle) TextView mCountryTitle;
    @BindView(R.id.countryImage) ImageView mCountryImage;
    public ViewHolderLocation(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }

    public void bindItem(int position, MainActivity context){
        int imageToDisplay = Data.locations[position].getImageID();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = getSimplesizedImage(imageToDisplay, context);
        mPlaceTitle.setText(Data.locations[position].getPlaceTitle());
        mCountryTitle.setText(Data.locations[position].getCountryLocation());
        mCountryImage.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }

    private Bitmap getSimplesizedImage(int imageToDisplay, MainActivity context) {
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inSampleSize = 4;

        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources() , imageToDisplay, options);
    }
}
```

}